# Firestore Security Rules what is the =** operator

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

What does the `=**` operator do?

Its part of the standard allow all read write code that comes with the beginning of a project.  If used in conjunction with the wildcard id `{userID}`.  Or does it cascade rules down the collection document chain.  According the the docs thats not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's call the *recursive wildcard syntax* and is [explained in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#hierarchical_data):

> If you want rules to apply to an arbitrarily deep hierarchy, use the
>   recursive wildcard syntax, {name=**}

Comment: Note that by using a wildcard {name=**} instead of {name} you may break your rules if you are referencing the name variable in your rule. This is because {name=**} resolve to the  "entire matching path segment". It caught me out and debugging this stuff is painful.